# Name of group of matrices with $\left|\det\right|=1$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, determinant

In $\operatorname{GL}(n),$ the group of $n\times n$ matrices, the matrices with determinant equal to $+1$ or $-1$ form a group. 
What is the name of that group and where can I find information about it?

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group

Comment: This group has no name known to me; it is not the special linear group.

Comment: You really need to specify a field $K$ over which the matrices are written, and write ${\rm GL}(n,K)$ or ${\rm GL}_n(K)$. I think the subgroup in question is sometimes denoted by ${\rm SL}^\pm(n,K)$.

Comment: The only constraint is that the field K is not of characteristic 2; actually I'm interested in this group within $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: It's hard to find any info on this group, even now I know how it is indicated.

Comment: Determinants of elements of ${\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$ can only be $1$ or $-1$, so ${\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z}) = {\rm SL}^\pm(n,{\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: Should have seen that myself, thanks.

Comment: And what is known about $\text{SL}^{\pm}(n,\mathbb{R})$?